# Where I can see the "keystore" details?

Tags: android

I tried to figure out how i can see the SHA-1 fingerprint, according to the Google guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start, I should do the following

For Windows Vista and Windows 7, run:

> > keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\your_user_name.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android "

But I cannot understand where i should run this trial in windows?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dSqLKIow7sY. The link demonstrates how to genearate a api key for google maps. Follow the tutorial

Comment: OK, thanks Maroun, this is the exact demonstrate that i looked for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run it directly in the `bin` sub-directory of your Java JDK directory (e.g. for me it is `C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin`) or add the `bin` directory to your `PATH` environment variable. If you do the latter, you can run the command from any command line prompt.